# How long does an account merge take?

Tags: support, status-completed

Yesterday, I requested that two accounts (and their rep) be merged; I followed the procedure provided, including the final acknowledgement after activating the two links emailed to me. As of this morning, the merge has not occurred. How long should this take to occur?

Correct account (the one I want remaining after the merge): https://english.stackexchange.com/users/246168/jeff-zeitlin

Incorrect account (the one that I want absorbed by the other):
https://english.stackexchange.com/users/246167/jeff-zeitlin

Comment: Mine took about a week. Though that was a few years back and it was a cross-stack merge. But be patient. It will happen. Meanwhile you can accrue rep and badges on your main account, nothing is holding it back.

Comment: @DanBron - Oh, not worried; I don't do SE for the rep, just because it's interesting. But I'd gotten the impression that it was more-or-less not-quite-instant; most other "Please Help!"-type requests - in multiple stacks - I've seen seemed to have been resolved within a day.

Comment: Cool, I'm the same re rep. As to the timing, it depends on the team's workload and priorities I guess. I think merges are manual or semi-manual. You did check the email addresses for both the old and the new account for "verification requests" from SE, yes?

Comment: @DanBron - Oh yes, definitely - and after I did the second one, I got the message about "this is going to merge the accounts" and do I really want to do this (at which point I clicked OK). :)

Comment: About **6 to 8 weeks**. [(/SO/joke)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/309993)

Comment: OK, as of this morning, it appears to have been taken care of. My thanks to Those Who Handle Such Requests.